# rails timestamp in both local server time and utc time / t.timestamps

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm curious if anyone has overriden the t.timestamps in rails migrations to provide both a local time and a utc time. Like:

```
updated_at
created_at
updated_at_utc
created_at_utc
```

Part of me thinks this is a really bad idea but if easily done would satisfy some internal complaints. I'm also thinking of nixing t.timestamps since we use paper clip and have the information there too.

I know we could do calculations but it would be nice to have both pieces of info there when accessing via MySQL. The business case is that 90% of our stuff takes place in our time zone and 10% outside time zone.

How would I override this?

thx

Comment: perhaps some advice orthogonal to your question...store the date once, UTC and wherever this value is displayed, convert it to local time.

Comment: probably what I'd want to do but other people are familiar with mysql iterface so just easier to have both times. more business than technical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just set the `utc` fields in a `before_save` callback.